# WPF Menu Control Similar to JIRA

Tags: wpf, menu, menuitem

I have been trying to create a WPF control similar to how JIRA's menu works, and Googling around for the past few days hasn't really shown me anything helpful for overriding the menu template (or if that is even what I should be doing).

As a reference here is the type of menu I am trying to implement:

[image]

[image]

As one can see from the images, I don't want the standard menu that displays a popup next to the current menu item list, but it should instead take over the container host and display the current parent menu item at the top and then its child items under it.

As I said, not sure menu is even the correct control to attempt to override, but I'm not really sure what else to try to Google either.  It seems tantalizing similar to menu (overriding the menu items is easy to get them to display the look and feel I want), the trouble is how to get the menu item's parent to show at the top and reuse the entire menu area... it's almost as if the menu item would somehow have to interact with the menu, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of the plug-in methodology of WPF.

If possible, it would also be nice to not have a write a completely new control, but style something else existing, if that is even possible.  If writing a new control is necessary, then I would do it, but this is more an excercise in wanting to know if it is even possible to style a menu (or something else) in this way so it can be easily reused across the application.

Comment: can you try using HambergerMenu from UWP toolkit something like this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/hamburgermenu

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I think I decided to just write a control that will show a list of radio buttons and dynamically change the list based on the item selected... the more research I do I think it is not possible to style menu the way I would like it.